# Asp.net MVC 5 Kendo Grid Url.Action passing three parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc, url.action

I have been googling for answer, but not have found anything that works so far.  I need to add a third parameter (table has three keys and the ActionResult complains if I do not include all three) to a link in a Kendo Grid column.  I have this code:

```
  columns.Bound(p => p.Line).ClientTemplate(
                            "<a href='" +
                            Url.Action("Details", "OrderLine") +
                            "?OrdId=#= OrdId #&Line=#=Line#'" +
                            ">#=Line#</a>"
                        );
```

I can pass two parameters successfully.  I tried the following:

```
                            columns.Bound(p => p.Line).ClientTemplate(
                            "<a href='" +
                            Url.Action("Details", "OrderLine") +
                            "?OrdId=#= OrdId #&Line=#=Line# #&OrdType=#=OrdType#'" +
                            ">#=Line#</a>"
                        );
```

I am fairly certain my formatting is not right.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an extra `#` before `&OrdType=...` which is probably causing Kendo's template system to throw an error.

Complete [fixed] code block:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Line).ClientTemplate(
     "<a href='" +
        Url.Action("Details", "OrderLine") +
        "?OrdId=#= OrdId #&Line=#=Line# #&OrdType=#=OrdType#'" +
        ">#=Line#</a>"
);
```

As a tip, to make things a little easier to read (in my opinion), I usually use `string.Format` like the following:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Line).ClientTemplate(
     string.Format("<a href='{0}?OrdId=#= OrdId #&Line=#=Line# #&OrdType=#=OrdType#'>#=Line#</a>", 
     Url.Action("Details", "OrderLine"))
);
```

Comment: The only thing I had to change is the following ?OrdId=#= OrdId #&Line=#= Line# &OrdType=#= OrdType#'"  Thanks!!!